# Playing MIDI files under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, midi

**UPDATE:** Found [a more detailed and comprehensive explanation here](https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2015/02/02/how-to-play-midi-files-under-ubuntu-linux/).

**Original Question:**

I'm trying to play MIDI files under Linux. This is what I found so far:

```
sudo apt-get install fluid-soundfont-gm timidity timidity-interfaces-extra
```

then run

```
timidity -iA
```

in terminal first to get started. It should give something like this

```
timidity -iA
Requested buffer size 32768, fragment size 8192
ALSA pcm 'default' set buffer size 32768, period size 8192 bytes
TiMidity starting in ALSA server mode
Opening sequencer port: 129:0 129:1 129:2 129:3
```

However, all that I got is:

```
$ timidity -iA
/etc/timidity/freepats.cfg: No such file or directory
timidity: Error reading configuration file.
Please check /etc/timidity/timidity.cfg
```

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/timidity/freepats.cfg` is part of the package `freepats` on Ubuntu 14.04.

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install freepats
```

Then try starting timidity again.

Comment: Not to necro an old thread... but you can use fluid if you want.  You have to edit /etc/timidity/timidity.cfg though, by defautl it looks for freepats but you can comment out that line and uncomment a couple other lines instead to use fluid-soundfonts.